# How to convert console data to text file in Java

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream, printstream

I'm trying to export my console output to the text file. This output also comes from the serial port. But, I couldn't do it, it prints only one line. Can anyone help me? 
The code that I wrote is below.

```
 String input = new String(buffer, 0, len); // convert buffer to string
        myLinkedList = removeComma(input); //format string data 
        String[] array = myLinkedList.toArray(new String[myLinkedList.size()]); // put array the formatted data


        PrintStream fileOut = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\khas\\Desktop\\output.txt"));
        System.setOut(fileOut);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println("");
```

Comment: I would recommend looking into a FileWriter instead

Comment: it prints in one line but it prints all you need?

Comment: are you calling this method more than once? and only the latest information is shown?

Comment: @Stultuske instead of PrintStream?

Comment: When it comes to writing (to) a file, I would, yes

Comment: @vmrvictor I want to print all the lines on the console

Comment: so remove the line system.setout(fileout) and will go to the console, but not to the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to mirror console output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908485/java-how-to-mirror-console-output-to-file)

Answer (score 3):

> it prints only one line

because you use `System.out.print(array[i] + " ");`,

you can change it to `System.out.println(array[i] + " ");`

Comment: oh no, this is for the data. Because data come as an array. After th,s loop, I also write System.out.println( " "); to go next line.

Comment: @BesteIskemleci You said `I couldn't do it`. What is the exact problem?

Comment: it prints only one line. I want to have all the lines on the console.

Comment: @Beste Iskemleci You want to write them into the file, also want to print them on console. the problem is, they have been put into the file, but did not appear on the console. 
 Am I Right?

Answer (score 0):

You need a stream to write to the console and to the file at the same time, you can create this stream by using `TeeOutputStream` part of [commons-io](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io) giving as a parameter the stream to the console and the stream to the file

```
PrintStream original = System.out; //the stream of the console
FileOutputStream fileOut = new 
FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\khas\\Desktop\\output.txt"); //the stream of your file


OutputStream outputtee = new TeeOutputStream(originalOut, fileOut); //join both streams
PrintStream printTee = new PrintStream(outputTee);
System.setOut(printTee); // and set as the default out
```