# How do you get the text in system.output.println?

Tags: java, output

On the output part of my IDE (where all the system.out.println textx appear), I have several lines of text. I want to get them and save them to a text file. What would be the possible code for this?

Comment: Well somewhere in your code you must have defined the `System.out.println` arguments. take them?

Comment: [Start reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241024/system-out-println-redirection-in-java/22241169#22241169) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859410/dynamically-run-java-code-with-process/18860632#18860632) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea/12945678#12945678)

Answer (score 2):

use [`System#setOut()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) to redirect output to `FileOutputStream` to redirect System output to file

```
 // for restore purpose 
 PrintStream oldOutStream = System.out;

 PrintStream outFile = new PrintStream(
            new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.txt", true));
 System.setOut(outFile);

 System.out.println("this will goto file");
```

I assume you know about logging framework and you are not trying to use this for logging something

Answer (score 0):

Yo can replce all sop with fileoutput strem and write everything in file

if you want to write log then you can use log4j

```
String content = "This is the content to write into file";

File file = new File("filename.txt");

// if file doesnt exists, then create it
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(content);
bw.close();
```